# The original file that was split in 2 other files, is there a way in git to see what went where?

Tags: git

My problem:

I am a code reviewer, I have a situation in GIT:

- before: `a.txt`

Then a developer decided to split the content of `a.txt` into 2 files and add a few changes all in one commit:

- after: `b.txt` + few changes and `c.txt` + few changes

Is there an easy way to see:

1. what came to b from a?
2. what came to c from a?
3. all extra changes apart from just moving stuff?

A specific command would help a lot.

A certain policy/workflow that prevents from problem like this (when there is no way to visually diff the changes) would also help.

**UPDATE**

Do not get confused by seeing a bounty awarded answer down below, I did not authorize it, because I don't think it's a good answer.

Comment: Please add info about what program you're using for viewing diffs.

Comment: i am using git cli

Comment: `git diff --find-copies` and `git blame` will show *some* of what you want, but not in a particularly nice/friendly form.

Comment: Could you share such a commit, or at least examples of the files before and after so that we have something to work with?

Comment: I would handle the situation the following way: 1. Make an identical copy of the file and commit. 2. Rename both files and commit. 3. Delete one part int the first file, the other part in the other file and commit. 4. Start with changes. In the commit message you could also explain why you needed all of this

Comment: [The discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAMAMitC-iyH_YOAsJcPpLcUbmX-Zun4MCL89Pxn2rr7Lu_m2cQ@mail.gmail.com/T/#u) on the main Git mailing list.

Comment: I have read the mailing list discussion. All well and nice, but a commit history should be clean enough to be reviewable without wizardry. So I am seconding @Christoph 's suggestion. Aleksey, if you are indeed a code reviewer, you should have the authority to reject & revert the commit and tell the author to do it again in the suggested fashion. Code reviews should have a teaching & learning aspect to them for both the reviewer and the reviewee. So the policy you asked for is: Commits which are difficult to review get rejected.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there an easy way to see:
>
> - what came to b from a?
> - what came to c from a?
> - all extra changes apart from just moving stuff?

I don't think there's really any way to extract this information other than visually inspecting the diff. However, it looks like we may be able to detect a split files using `git diff` along with the `-C` argument.  For example, I start with a file that contains 38 lines, and move 24 into one file and 14 into another (and delete the original).  `git diff --name-status` just tells me that I have renamed one file and added another:

```
R060    lorem.txt       fileA
A       fileB
```

But if we modify our command line to detect copies:

```
git diff --name-status -C30 HEAD^
```

We get:

```
C060    lorem.txt       fileA
R039    lorem.txt       fileB
```

The `-C30` argument says "consider a file a copy if it is at least 30% similar to another file included in the commit". Note that there is a corresponding `-M` option that controls rename detection; it defaults to `50%`.

> A certain policy/workflow that prevents from problem like this would also help.

What exactly are you trying to prevent?  There's not really anyway to distinguish "I split a file into two new files" from "I deleted a file and created two new files".

You could in theory prevent commits that both introduce new files *and* modify existing files.  That would be relatively easy with a `pre-receive` hook, for example.  But that's such a common situation, I'm not sure you'd want to do this in practice.

For the above, a `pre-receive` hook like the following might work:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      

while read old new ref; do
        while read type name; do
                if [ "$type" = "A" ]; then
                        has_new=1
                else
                        has_mod=1
                fi
        done < <(git show --name-status --format='' $new)
done

if [ "$has_new" = 1 -a "$has_mod" = 1 ]; then
        echo "ERROR: commits may not both create and modify files" >&2
        exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

We could alternatively use our "split detection", discussed earlier, and implement something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read old new ref; do
    git diff --name-status -C30 $old $new |
        awk '
            {total[$2]++}
            END {for (i in total) if (total[i] > 1) exit 1}
        '

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "ERROR: detected a split file"
        exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```

This will exit with an error if any file shows up as the "old name" for a file more than once. Trying to push to a repository using this `pre-receive` hook, using the example given in the first part of this answers, get me:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.46 KiB | 1.46 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: ERROR: detected a split file
To upstream
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Maybe that helps?  Without extensive testing I would worry about false positives with this solution.

Comment: i want to prevent a situation when there is no way to visually diff the changes

Comment: See my update regarding copy detection, and let me know if that is heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: My idea is to recreate back the source file manually from splitted ones, and to compare it with original version (before split). This approach helped me with reviewing even more distributed content, making sure, that some code parts are still verbatim copies.

---

My issue/solution:
It was a file core.c, that contented a few code chunks like

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
  A_op1();
#else
  B_op1();
#endif
```

A developer had distributed a content of core.c to three files. Something retains in core.c; something - goes to (new) coreA.c or coreB.c, depending on the platform macro. Moreover, some addition code was introduced.

I manually gathered parts, pretended to be copy-pasted into single file tmp_core.c and compared it with original core.c with vimdiff. At the same time, I inspected the commit (e.g. with tig) on my second display. That allows me to distinguish copy-paste and code changes.