# How can I save color output from git to some text-processor file on Windows?

Tags: git

For the sake of doing better code reviews, I wish I could preserve the colors as I save stdout of git to some (not sure which one) text format file, so that I can open it for editing and enjoy the colors on Windows.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Try [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) a console for Windows and use the option "copy as html". Also you can try [NppExport plugin for Notepad++ 32-bit](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/nppexport-for-notepad-export-highlighted-code-in-html-rtf-format/) it works really well at copy-&-paste with formatting - try the "Copy All Formats" option and try to paste in a doc, email, or rtf editor - the editor must be able to support formatting so it would never work with text only.

Answer (score 1):

You can force `git` commands to always output the ansi color escape codes, even when being written to a file or piped to another command using the `--color=always`flags. this results in output that looks like e.g.:

```
ESC[33mcommit 6d5ef5dd01337c83a27290e54ddc9a3370f9ffa4ESC[m
```

On linux if you save this to a file, you can view it in color with e.g.`less -R` - however you will need a Windows application capable of translating these codes back into color - I'm afraid I don't know anything about Windows to know what to suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

What `@match` said — using `--color=auto` — combined with any tool
which is able to interpret those
["ANSI color sequences"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)
and produce *something* which makes use of them.

[Quick searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=ansi+color+escape+to+html) turns up
[this](https://github.com/rburns/ansi-to-html) which looks like
having been created for the exact purpose you're after.

(Well, and [it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/)
that it's possible to set up plain Windows console in a way that mere running
`type` on a file containing those escape sequences would make rendering
of that file actually use colors.)

On the other hand, why do you need this?
It's easier to use a tool which would present you with diff view etc, no?

BTW Git for Windows supports colors on the terminal just OK;
may be you just have failed to somehow turn this on?

Comment: i wish it was easier, some advanced scenarios are only supported by git in its latest versions (no tool around knows them): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350398/the-original-file-that-was-split-in-2-other-files-is-there-a-way-in-git-to-see


so git output is my only source, which i cannot save, hence the question

Comment: @AlekseyBykov, updated my answer to also mention direct/wrapped support for ANSI color code sequences by Windows consoles.

Comment: windows console indeed supports colors while displaying output, my question was about preserving this output to an editable file, so i can go through it and edit it

Comment: html isn't the most convenient format to edit, but i appreciate your answer, the git part of the question is clear, need to find a tool that can save to doc or rtf

Comment: @AlekseyBykov quick googling yields [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-can-i-import-an-html-page-into-word-while/329225f2-7d14-4e6b-a284-9bcb1cdac8c1)—see the comment at the bottom re. saving the html as `.mht` in IE and then opening the latter with MSWord.